# How to remove first part of URL string in column value with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm struggling to remove the first part of my URLs in column myId in csv file.

my.csv

```
myID

https://mybrand.com/trigger:open?Myservice=Email&recipient=brn:zib:b1234567-9ee6-11b7-b4a2-7b8c2344daa8d
```

desired output for myID

```
b1234567-9ee6-11b7-b4a2-7b8c2344daa8d
```

my code:

```
df['myID'] = df['myID'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('https://mybrand.com/trigger:open?Myservice=Email&recipient=brn:zib:'))
```

output in myID (first letter 'b' is missing in front of the string):

```
1234567-9ee6-11b7-b4a2-7b8c2344daa8d
```

the above code removes `https://mybrand.com/trigger:open?Myservice=Email&recipient=brn:zib:` However it also removes the first letter from myID if there is one in front of the ID, if it's a number then it remains unchanged.

Could someone help with this? thanks!

Comment: you can also split by ``:`` and take last element, ``df.myID.str.split(":").str[-1]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex replacement here:

```
df['myID'] = df['myID'].str.replace('^.*:', '', regex=True)
```

This approach is to simply remove all content from the start of `MyID` up to, and including, the final colon.  This would leave behind the UUID you want to keep.

Comment: You can remove the optional parameter `regex=True`, its by default `True` ;).

Answer (score 0):

With lstrip you remove all characters from a string that match the set of characters you pass as an argument. So:

```
string = abcd
test = string.lstrip(ad)
print(test)
```

If you want to strip the first x characters of the string, you can just slice it like an array. For you, that would be something like:

```
df['myID'] = df['myID'].map(lambda x: x[:-37])
```

However, for this to work, the part you want to get from the string should have a constant size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **re** (if the part before what you want to extract is always the same)

```
import re

idx = re.search(r':zib:', myID)
myNewID = myID[idx.end():]
```

Then you will have :

```
myNewID

'b1234567-9ee6-11b7-b4a2-7b8c2344daa8d'
```